# How can I generate Affirmative and Negative responses from a statement or question?

Tags: questions

I'm writing troubleshooting that consists of questions and positive or negative responses like so:

Is the television plugged in?
Affirmative: The television is plugged in.
Negative: The television is not plugged in.

I want to aggregate the responses as the troubleshooting continues so that the next step would look like this:

*The television is plugged in.*
Is the power light bright red?

The problem is that I want a computer program to take my questions and generate the affirmative and negative responses and due to grammar this isn't always trivial.

Trivial:
Is there bright red light?
+ There is bright red light.
- There is not bright red light.

Question form:
Is there [...]

Affirmative form: 
There is [...]

Negative form:
There is not [...]

That's easy, they're all simple sentence prefixes.  But for others it is not so simple:

Does the TV change channels?
Yes the TV changes channels.
No it does not change channels.

Is there sound coming from the speakers.
Yes there is sound coming from the speakers.
No there is no sound coming from the speakers.

Are more than three of the lights lit?
No, less than three lights are lit.
Yes, more than three lights are lit.

If I could figure out a handful of templates for this that could easily be inverted by simple cut and paste type operations I could make it work.

Also that should probably be "3 or fewer lights are lit" "3 or more lights are lit"

Comment: What is the real purpose here?  Even if you had a handful of templates and a data file the contained the appropriate fragment and which template to use and coded up the logic to properly formulate the responses, why not just store the text of the question and the two responses?

Comment: Jim: it would cut down on manual data entry